# APK makes two files

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I built an app Android Studio application with Firebase realtime DB.
The problem is when I install its APK file in mobile it makes two runnable files starting from different activities.
I am sharing the code of both two files that starts from both runnable files in mobile. Thanks in advance.

FILE THAT I want to be the Launcher activity:

```
    package com.example.Paanki;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.foundationapp.R;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        Button btn;
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btnproceed);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainSelect.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

The Other Runnable File

```
    package com.example.Paanki




import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

  import com.example.foundationapp.R;

 public class MainSelect extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btndonor,btntrans;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){}
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_select);

    btndonor= findViewById(R.id.donor);
    btntrans= findViewById(R.id.trans);


    btndonor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btntrans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterTrans.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

 }
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
     this.finishAffinity();
 }


  }
```

Comment: Please share your manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check your manifest file. This kind of thing happens when you write an App startup Intent-filter into more than one activity in a manifest file.

App startup intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```